# jQuery/Javascript - how to get width of browser window in all browsers (especially Safari) that is consistent with CSS breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have been attempting to use Javascript or jQuery to retrieve the browser window width and make it consistent with my CSS media queries.

When I set the browser so that the rulers (and my CSS) show it's exactly 768px wide, here are the results I obtain with jQuery ($(window).width()) and Javascript (window.innerWidth).

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Browser, OS                   | $(window).width() | window.innerWidth |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chrome, MacOS 10.13           |      753          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Safari, MacOS 10.13           |      768          |        783        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chrome, MacOS 10.14           |      768          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Safari, MacOS 10.14           |      768          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Chrome, Windows 10            |      753          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Edge, Windows 10              |      751          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Internet Explorer, Windows 10 |      768          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Opera, Windows 10             |      753          |        768        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, jQuery (which I'd originally been using) is all over the place, which I found surprising, and is causing issues on my site. It seems plain Javascript with window.innerWidth is much more consistent, but returns the wrong value in Safari (latest version) on MacOS 10.13. Safari is used by a large part of our audience, so I'd like to use something that will return 768 for all browsers when the browser is set to 768.

Is there any other Javascript or jQuery property I can try?

Edit (to answer comment)

```
html {
   font-size: 100%;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
   line-height: 1.42857143;
   margin: 0;
   font-family: 'Weissenhof-Grotesk', Tahoma, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What does the CSS for the page you're doing this look like for the `html` and `body` elements?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - please see edits. I got this from Chrome's inspector so it should be everything that's being applied. I'm using Bootstrap 3 if that matters.

Comment: I don't have a Mac handy to test the problematic case (Safari/MacOS), sadly. I'd certainly add a padding/margin reset to `html` and `body`, and I'd probably apply my usual `box-sizing` reset (from Paul Irish) as well: `html { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;} *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; } body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` ([Formatted copy](https://pastebin.com/4er2wqE8)) It may well not help, but...